# How do I find the correct data type to convert a string to?

Tags: c++, string, vector, type-conversion

I have a string vector which contains numerical values at each position of the vector, I want to find out how I can let my programme judge how to convert the values within the string, for example convert them to doubles OR ints Or floats when suitable.

```
vector <string> SeperatedValues;
SeperatedValues.push_back("22");
SeperatedValues.push_back("4.1");
SeperatedValues.push_back("80.41");
SeperatedValues.push_back("2");
```

Is there any built in functions that can do this for me!

I can convert everything to doubles but that isn't efficient as the value within the string may fit within an integer and not require a double!

Comment: I don't know where your numbers are coming from, but how about not storing them as `strings` in the first place? :)

Comment: The standard library has function that attempt a conversion and throw if it fails (since `C++11`). But brute force for finding the least possible data type may slow your program much more than simply using a wide numerical type.

Comment: @CompuChip I would love to do that as it would make love easier, but these number are being extracted from another vector that contains a mix of numbers and characters, its something to do with the way they are being in putted to my system! :)

Comment: I'd suggest you should profile your code to see if this "efficiency" gain is really warranted.

Comment: @StoryTeller, that means that I either have to compromise memory or speed? if i understood correctly!

Comment: @Aboudi, exactly. It's the programmers eternal dilemma, I'm afraid. Which is why I again suggest that you check if you need it before you go for it. And even if you do, try going for a smaller set of numerical types. It may not be the best gain in memory usage, but it may just be enough.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks speed is more important where I need it!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string has "." character, if it doesn't convert to int, otherwise to double

Comment: What about `"5.36E-10"`, that's a string for a float as well. You should always reach for what the standard library has before hacking your own solution.

Comment: Depending on locale, that "." may be a "," (and possibly other characters - not sure).